# SharePoint 2013 - Custom save button - Handling click using Javascirpt

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, custom-form

We have created a custom list with a cutom edit form using Visual Studio 2013.

At the bottom of the page, we need to add a button which will perform custom tasks and submit the form for update.  I'm currently unsing a "SharePoint:RenderingTemplate" control

For example, on the "click" event of our custom button, we need to assign values based of values entered by the user.

So what I need to do on the client is something like this:

- Call the PreSaveItem method;
- Call our custom method;
- Do a PostBack of the FORM.

As I read, the PreSaveItem method will be a good place to do my stuff, but I cannot discriminate the caller (eg. the SAVE button or my "Custom button")... the event data is not passed to the function;

One way to achieve my goal would be to create a server-side Custom Button with C# code.

But If I were to add a new button using XSLT (in a WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart control) I could do something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="mySubmit" value="My submit" onclick="javascript: if (!PreSaveItem()) return false; foo(); { ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit') }"/>
```

Is it possible to dynamically generate the "onclick" part within my RenderingTemplate?

Thx

Comment: What happens when someone modifies an item with the gridview,and doesn't click the save button? I think it would be better to build this as an event handler, not a modification of the save button.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure i can understand correctly your question, but it seems to me that you want to submit a form via "original" save button. But would like to do your own code in between. If that's correct, what I usually do is to return 'false' in PreSaveItem. Then do all the things I need to do and then submit form with javascript like this:

```
function triggerPostback() {
    var saveButtonName = $('input[value$="Save"]').attr('name');
    WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(saveButtonName, "", true, "", "", false, true));
}
```

Basically i grab an existing save button, then construct form submit code and submit via WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions