# Submit EditForm event handler with CSR/Jslink

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-form, jslink, client-side-rendering

Is it possible to add custom event handler to the submit button of Edit Form through CSR/JSLink?

If yes, any documentation/links or example that I could use to achieve this with pure CSR?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be possible with JSLink. But, you can change the event handler of default save button as well as you can create a custom save button using JavaScript (in content editor or script editor web parts).

Check below references which might help you:

1. [Custom Save Button On Custom SharePoint List Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/custom-save-button-on-custom-sharepoint-list-forms)
2. [Create Custom Save and Redirect Button On A SharePoint Form](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-custom-save-and-redirect-button-on-a-sharepoint-form)
3. [SharePoint 2013 - Custom save button - Handling click using JavaScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98008/sharepoint-2013-custom-save-button-handling-click-using-javascirpt)
4. [How to trigger the click event of the SharePoint OOTB list's new form Save button?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117147/how-to-trigger-the-click-event-of-the-sharepoint-ootb-lists-new-form-save-butto)

Comment: Also, there might be other easier solutions based on what you are going to achieve with custom event handler. I will be able to suggest if you can add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi @David, does this answers your question? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't exactly use CSR itself to do that, because you can't hook into the rendering of the button.

What you need to do is create a custom `PreSaveAction` function which will be called by SharePoint when the submit button is clicked.

You could *potentially* use something like `OnPostRender` in the CSR framework to define the function or something, but that seems unnecessary.

You **definitely** can use the JSLink property of the edit form web part to pull in a custom script file in which you define your `PreSaveAction` function:

[image: screen shot of JSLink in edit form web part]

You can learn a bit more about `PreSaveAction` [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/what-is-the-difference-between-presaveaction-and-presaveitem-on-sharepoint-l) and [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx), and of course you can just search for "SharePoint PreSaveAction" to find plenty more resources.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Dylan. I didn't know that CSR is available for the list forms!